# How to add Table data to Before last Table Data Column using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have html table in partial view.

I want to add more table data to table row. Need to mention I have created only one table row having all table data inside horizontally.

I need to add more table data after button click event. But my last table data is `Total`, so i need to add table data before `Total` column. It is html mark up so I don't have way to show that.

My table is like that.

```
<table>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>Total</td></tr>
</table>
```

I want to add new column before `Total` column, like that.

```
<table>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>Add New Column</td><td>Total</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried not show correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you mean, but check this DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/UDV64/

Is that what you want?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add').on('click', function(){
        var $getCol = $('#myTable tr > td');
        $getCol.eq($getCol.length-1).before('<td>New</td>');
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT -> Already posted:
[Add table row in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery?rq=1)

This is what you will need to use: http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/

You can use this with `.append` or `.insertAfter`

jQuery has great documentation so make sure you read through and look at the examples.

Comment: I no need to append on last row I need append before last node

Comment: He quite clearly states column not row.

Comment: My bad, I confused the question @Mike Campbell. Thanks yeyene for editing question, your answer was excellent.